# Did you try Doloto "AJAX application optimization tool" ? have any comments/concerns about?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, optimization

MSDN launched [**Doloto**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee423534.aspx), Doloto is an AJAX application optimization tool, especially useful for large and complex Web 2.0 applications that contain a lot of code.

Anyone tried it till now, have any comments/concerns about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been trying to optimize the javascript of a medium-sized website using Doloto. I would have to say I'm a bit underwhelmed. While seeing how much Doloto *could* optimize a site is really popular, I suspect actually implementing it is not very common. In fact, Doloto has been crashing every time it attempts to write this site's javascript. I'm sure I can get through this error, but it is definitely annoying.

I've asked a question similar to yours on the Doloto forums if you're interested:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/doloto/thread/b7519f70-2c02-4548-88f2-1a4af19bf329